# How to connect multiple databases located on different physical machine in spring MVC and hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi i am new in spring hibernate and i want to connect to multiple databases located on different physical machines ?
can some one help me on that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have dataSource for two different databases in Spring application. You need to add this configuration in the **dispatcher-servlet.xml** file.

```
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>@mssql.driver@</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>@mssql.url@</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>@mssql.user@</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>@mssql.password@</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- DataSource bean for egpnew Database -->
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="reportDataSource"  destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>@mssql.driver@</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>@mssql.egpurl@</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>@mssql.user@</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>@mssql.password@</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
    </bean>
```

But don't forget to have unique id in both bean definations.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: sorry i don't have sufficient reputation to upvote your answer,Thank you so much